# How to represent a point cloud in the pseudocode of an algorithm?

Tags: type-theory, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-foundations

I am writing a scientific paper in which I describe some algorithms (using pseudocode) that have point clouds as inputs. In these algorithms, I need a mathematical structure to represent a point cloud. I need this mathematical structure to permit to access the $i$-th point in a point cloud. I have read some papers that use sets to represent point clouds, but if I use a set I won't be able to access the $i$-th point of that set. On the other hand, I was thinking of using an array of points to represent a point cloud. However, I also need some operations related to sets such as $\in$ and $\subset$.

To make it clear, the algorithms I mentioned are already implemented using the Point Cloud Library (PCL). In this library point clouds are C++ std::vector<>. **I am not interested in their implementation but in the correct mathematical structure for a point cloud that include the operations mentioned in the previous paragraph. This with the objective of describing them in a scientific paper.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can implement all those operations in an array, if efficiency of implementation is not an issue, then an array will suffice.

Comment: "should" is a matter of opinion, and we're looking for objectively answerable questions.  Please [edit] your question to define all requirements and metrics you'll use to evaluate answers (and that voters should use to vote on proposed anwers).  As Russel hints, please tell us in the question whether you have any requirements regarding efficiency, or if you'll accept any data structure that supports all of those operations.

Comment: You are right. I added a paragraph to make my question clear. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use both a vector and set at the same time. The vector would provide efficient $i$-th element access, ande the set would provide efficient subset checks and membership tests.

In order to maintain that the vector and set have the same elements, write operations need to be performed on both the vector and the set, so the time complexities are added together. But read operations can be performed on the more efficient of the two data structures, so the minimum of the two time complexities is taken.

The following table gives a summary of the desired operations and their time complexities for each data structure.

| Operation | Vector | Set | Vector and set together |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Insert/Delete | $O(1)$ amortized | $O(\log n)$ | $O(1) + O(\log n) = O(\log n)$ |
| $\subset$ | $O(n \log n)$ | $O(n)$ | $\min(O(n \log n), O(n)) = O(n)$ |
| $\in$ | $O(n)$ | $O(\log n)$ | $\min(O(n), O(\log n) = O(\log n)$ |
| Access $i$th element | $O(1)$ | $O(n)$ | $\min(O(1), O(n)) = O(1)$ |

Comment: The OP explicitly said he is not interested in an implementation.

Answer (score -1):

What about $$C:=\{i\in [1,n]: P_i\}$$